# Libgds.so в Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lib

Не могу найти на компе данную библиотеку и в интернете ни как не наткнусь. Должно быть где-то в firebird*, но пока не разобрался в каком пакете искать найти.

```
$ dpkg -L firebird-dev
dpkg-query: предупреждение: список файлов пакета «firebird-dev» отсутствует; предполагаем, что на данный момент у пакета нет установленных файлов
Пакет «firebird-dev» не содержит файлов (!)
$ sudo apt-get install firebird-dev
[sudo] пароль для alexandr: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет firebird-dev самой новой версии (2.5.6.27020.ds4-2).
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-45 linux-headers-4.8.0-45-generic linux-image-4.8.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-45-generic linux-signed-image-4.8.0-45-generic
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 5 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 15 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н]
```

Comment: Поставь пакет firebird-dev как и хотел, а потом создай симлинки

`ln -s /usr/lib/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so.0`
`ln -s /usr/lib/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so`